# Can we find the contrapositive of the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The implicit function theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) is a tool which allows relations to be converted to functions of several real variables. It does this by representing the relation as the graph of a function: My **question** is: Can we find the **contrapositive** of the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: What exactly are you after? Could you state what your input should be and what kind of output you are after?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I am seeking the logical contrapositive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem says that if a certain matrix is invertible, then there exist a certain $U$ and a certain $V$ and a certain function $g$.  (The article you linked gives the specifics.)  So, the contrapositive is:  If there doesn't exist that $U$ or there doesn't exist that $V$ or there doesn't exist that $g$, then the matrix is not invertible.